# Binary search - multiple searched values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, binary-search

I using binary search for searching rows range that should be rendered in my app. `GridRow` has 3 properties: `top`, `height` and `bottom` and list of rows is sorted.

Example:

I passing `30px` to my first call of `rowBinarySearch`, in next line `140` and `firstIndex` to speedup search. I return `lastIndex + 1` for fix visibility of last row in my array:

```
const firstIndex = rowBinarySearch(rows, 30);
const lastIndex = rowBinarySearch(rows, 140, firstIndex);

return range.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1);
```

[image: diagram]

Search function implementation:

```
function rowBinarySearch(arr: GridRow[], val: number, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1): number {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    if (mid < 0)
        return 0;
    if (val === arr[mid].top)
        return mid;
    if (start >= end)
        return mid; // original version should return -1 if element dont exist
    return val < arr[mid].top
        ? rowBinarySearch(arr, val, start, mid - 1)
        : rowBinarySearch(arr, val, mid + 1, end);
}
```

Expected behavior:
1. Remove hacky return commented in commented listing above
2. Find first row that `top` value of row is lower then searched value
3. I would be great if shouldnt increment `lastIndex` by `1`

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Is the height always 25, and are the rows always adjacent to eachother?

Comment: 25px is default row height, each row may be different. Yes, every row is adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Remove hacky return commented in commented listing above

This is not a hacky return. A recursive algorithm always needs a base case, and `start >= end` is exactly the base case this recursion depends on.

It is the preceding `return` that is not conventional. If all integer values are allowed for `val`, then `val === arr[mid].top` is a rare case, and it does not need special treatment really. Think of what should happen when `val` is `arr[mid].top + 1`. It should be the same (assuming a `height` of more than 1).

Also the first `return` for when `mid < 0` is not necessary, unless you plan to call this function with negative values for either `start` or `end`. And acutally you risk to do this for `end` in recursive calls, but see next point on how to avoid that.

> 2. Find first row that top value of row is lower then searched value

Currently, your algorithm is not correct: when instead of 140, you pass 120 in the second call, the return value is 2 units less, while you only "climb" one row.

I would suggest defining `end` as the first index *after* the current range. This is in line with how parameters are defined for functions like `.slice`.

> 3. I would be great if shouldnt increment lastIndex by 1

You should not strive to do that, since it is only logical that if you use the same function for both finding the starting row and the ending row, that you want one more row selected than `lastIndex - firstIndex`. So just add 1 and don't worry about it.

Here is a fixed algorithm:

```js
function rowBinarySearch(arr, val, start = 0, end = arr.length) {
    if (start >= end) return end - 1; // base case
    const mid = (start + end) >> 1; // Use shift, so you don't need to `floor`.
    return val < arr[mid].top
        ? rowBinarySearch(arr, val, start, mid)
        : rowBinarySearch(arr, val, mid + 1, end);
}

// Demo
const rows = Array.from({length: 7}, (_, id) => ({
    id, top: id*25, bottom: id*25+25, height: 25
}));
const firstIndex = rowBinarySearch(rows, 30);
const lastIndex = rowBinarySearch(rows, 140, firstIndex);
console.log(rows.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1).map(JSON.stringify).join("\n"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented this solution in my app and it works  great.